# RichSnippets from schema.org MusicGroup: which member property should one use?

Tags: schema.org, rich-snippets

see http://schema.org/MusicGroup

There are two kinds of members defined, one from the parent schema 'Organization' (member) and one from the actual 'MusicGroup' (musicGroupMember). Also, MusicGroup specifies a logo while the parent schema Thing also specifies an image. I dont understand how this was meant to use, because the logo *is* the image of the item (thing) MusicGroup and the musicGroupMember *is* the member of the organisation MusicGroup.

Has anyone already understood those differences and has might share some usage advice?

TIA,

.rhavin;)

Answer (score 0):

When there's any confusion it's usually best to use the properties from the specific Type, rather than similar properties inherited from Parent Types. So I'd suggest using musicGroupMember for members of a band.

As for the difference between logo and image - use "logo" for the band's logo and then you can use the inherited "image" property for a photo of the band.

Comment: "it's usually best" … would you please back that up with some references, background-infomation, experience or something like that? In the perspective of comparability of different childs of the same parent, i'd tend to assume the opposite of your advice.

Comment: It's based on what I've read over the past 10 months on the public-vocabs mailing list (the official mailing list where all new schema.org proposals are debated before being implemented, & where the minutiae of schema.org implementation are discussed). 

Background info/experience: I'm not claiming to be an expert, nor is there one true way to do things. I've submitted one proposal for a new schema.org "type" to the mailing list (still in consideration) & I've contributed to some of the discussions on the mailing list. But there are many people on the list much more knowledgeable than me.